# Infopath option button control - modify button count

Tags: infopath

I have an InfoPath Option Button control on a template and need to add an additional option button to the control.  Any ideas would help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean programmatically or you just don't know how to add a button to an existing group (since the default is to create a new group)?

If you just want to add another button to an existing group the easiest way is to copy one of the existing buttons and paste it. Then double click (or right click and select) to go to the properties screen and change the "value when selected".

Comment: Just want to add additional button to allready created option control, control was created with 3 buttons want to add 4th.
Not programmatically.

Comment: Second paragraph explains exactly how to do that.